# rake db:schema:dump is not producing schema for all databases

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rake

I have this project and I need to integrate a bunch of databases into my Rails project.

This is the database configuration that I have to work with.

**$ nano config/database.yml**

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  reconnect: true
  pool: 5
  username: user_xyz
  password: 123456
  database: database1
  host: localhost


  database_2:
    adapter: mysql2
    reconnect: false
    pool: 5
    username: user_xyz
    password: 123456
    database: database2
    host: 192.168.2.100

  database_3:
    adapter: mysql2
    reconnect: false
    pool: 5
    username: user_xyz
    password: 123456
    database: database3
    host: 192.168.2.101

  database_4:
    adapter: mysql2
    reconnect: false
    database: database4
    pool: 5
    username: user_xyz
    password: 123456
    host: 192.168.2.102
```

I need to update the schema inside `db/schema.rb` but unfortunately it's only producing the schema for production (database1).

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:schema:dump
```

I can't just run this as it complains:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:schema:dump
rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter
```

What do I need to do to get all of these databases into `db/schema.rb`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Austio's answer is a good one. Here is some extra detail on how to implement a solution. Create a new rake file, e.g., `lib/tasks/schema_dump.rake`, and add the following contents:

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :schema do
    desc 'dumps the schema of database_1 to db/schema_db1.rb'
    task :dump_db1 => :environment do
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection 'database_4'
      File.open(Rails.root.join('db', 'schema_db1.rb'), 'w') do |file|
        ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.dump ActiveRecord::Base.connection, file
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now when you run `rake db:schema:dump` it'll dump the schema of your primary database to `db/schema.rb` (like traditional Rails).  But when you run `rake db:schema:dump_db1`, it'll dump the schema of your `database_1` block into `db/schema_db1.rb`.

You can create similar tasks for your other database blocks and have a schema file for each database.

Comment: This worked great, but I did have to use just 'schema' and instead of 'db:schema' like 'rake schema:dump_db1'. Maybe different rails versions? I found what to run by running 'rake -T'.

Comment: You're correct, the example solution should be nested inside a `namespace :db do` block.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to establish a connection to each database that you would like to schema dump on.  Here is example for database_4

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection 'database_4'
```

Then when you run schema dump, it will dump the current database you have a connection with.  I'm not sure if the rake task has arguments to copy it to a different file name, so you may have to rename the file.